# how to resolve ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly Exception

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly 
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load assembly

I have tried to resolve it like clean bin, obj rebuild again said in the previous results of this issue but it doesn't work for me. Does anyone have a solution for this issue, please help me.

Note: I am having an error in `Mono.Android` in the References of portable code is this the problem and how to resolve this also?

This is the error I get:

> Error      The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SampleProject, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
>   File name: 'SampleProject.dll'
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() SampleProject.Android           Build

Comment: Can you include a full [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) to your question?

Answer (score 2):

**Mono.Android** is purely a native Android dll for Xamarin.Android
using this in your portable project will throw an error (Of Course.)

This might be the issue if the error still persists after removing the dll then I would suggest you remove the bin obj folders and clean build and in case it still persists you should upload the output window for the debug build as well as error list explanation for this particular error.

Answer (score 2):

=> delete all from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin

=> delete .vs folder

=> restart visual studio in run as admin(if not).

=> clean and rebuild.

Comment: i usually get this stupid error without no reason and by this some random steps i get rid of it mostly

Comment: can you tell me your project location?is it in root drive(D:) or default path?

Comment: There is only one drive C:, and i previously fixed this error but forgot how?

Comment: put your project to root drive.if its in defalut path.that long path may cause this error while getting dll's path.try this